# How to hash a password with SHA512

Tags: c#, security, encryption, passwords, hash

In my previous question I was told to hash passwords instead of encrypt, and that turned out to be correct. Problem is, I've never dealt with hashing passwords before and all the docs say SHA512 which I've tried to use on a test account to no avail. I'm not sure where to go from here. The code comments give me the example "encrypted" string as they call it, and it's "FA35A0194E3BE7024CEFB1839CBFC922" which I'm not sure how to format it like that with SHA512 since all it takes and gives back is a byte array or stream from the `ComputeHash()` method:

```
byte[] hashedPassword = HashAlgorithm.Create("SHA512").ComputeHash( ??? );
```

UPDATE

I've tried printing out the UTF8Encoding.GetString on the bytes, but it just displays a bunch of bullshit characters that look nothing like the one in the example docs.

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you're asking. Are you asking us to help you learn how to use the SHA512 class in C#? You could start with the MSDN docs here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha512.aspx

Comment: OK asawyer, I will edit this...

Comment: Hey asawyer, is that good enough?

Answer (score 5):

Hashing with plain SHA-512 is still wrong. Use PBKDF2 which is exposed via [Rfc2898DeriveBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx).

It returns raw bytes, which you should encode with either hex or base64.

You can do hex encoding with:

```
BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-","")
```

Comment: ugh... i'm trying to work with a shitpile legacy system that requires this SHA512 hashing function that I thought was encryption in my previous question - I just don't know how to get the text based on the bytes!

Comment: @james to get a string from byte[] you would need to use encoding, for example: `string data = new UTF8Encoding(false).GetString(bytes);`

Comment: @Igor Because plain SHA-512 is fast. The most important threat for password hashing is guessing many potential passwords. If you iterate the hash 10k times, then cracking becomes 10k times as expensive. PBKDF2 is essentially such an iterated hash function.

Answer (score 1):

You sure it said 512 because that's 128, but anyway you could use something like

```
System.String Hashed = System.BitConverter.ToString(((System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512)new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512Managed()).ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("NotHashedPass"))).Replace("-","");

MessageBox.Show(Hashed);
```

but id recommend at least using a salt.

Comment: Now you see why I'm confused here?

Comment: @godzcheater how about separating that line into variables.  No points given for making one liners when you are trying to help someone understand something.

Comment: @Savage if you saw the original question you would know that he has no idea what any of his code dose but,
`
            System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512 SHA512 = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512Managed();
            System.Byte[] Hash = SHA512.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("NotHashedPass"));// if you want to add a salt just do "NotHashedPass" + "SaltHere"
            System.String HashStr = System.BitConverter.ToString(Hash).Replace("-", "");

            MessageBox.Show(HashStr);`

Answer (score 1):

Please see tutorial here:
http://www.obviex.com/samples/hash.aspx

From the tutorial:
"These code samples demonstrate how to hash data and verify hashes. It supports several hashing algorithms. To help reduce the risk of dictionary attacks, the code prepends random bytes (so-called salt) to the original plain text before generating hashes and appends them to the generated ciphertext (original salt value will be needed for hash verification). The resulting ciphertext is base64-encoded. IMPORTANT: DATA HASHES CANNOT BE DECRYPTED BACK TO PLAIN TEXT"